# How to return primary key from oracle merge query

Tags: oracle, merge, oracle10g, sequence, sql-returning

I want to return the primary key from an oracle merge query. 
I'm using a single statement to insert if not exist and I don't want to use procedure or function to do so..

this is the sample query

```
merge into myTable e
  using (select :empname name from dual) s
  on (UPPER(TRIM(e.empname)) = UPPER(TRIM(s.name)))
  when not matched then insert (empname) 
    values (s.name)
```

and I need to get another primary key field of the myTable. the primary key is inserted using sequence and trigger

I tried adding  `RETURNING empID into :empId`  but it gives error

Comment: It "gives an error" because [there is no facility to use returning into](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606). However, if you want to return the PK _by definition_ you have to return it into something, which means you're using a wrapper of some description. What is wrong with this wrapper being a PL/SQL block. If you do not want it to be a procedure/function you are going to have to specify what you _do_ want to use otherwise it's impossible to answer this question well.

Comment: I am using a single oracle query to do so. the :empId I'm passing to this query as output parameter. Is it possible to get the output parameter value from a single merge query?

Comment: You might be interested to read this - http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=413

Answer (score 12):

There's a problem.

1. `Merge Into` doesn't support `Returning Into`, so that won't work.
2. The sequence will not always be used, because it's only used when inserting new records.
3. Getting the existing value of a sequence won't work, because you get an error if you want to query Sequence.currval when the sequence wasn't used in the current session yet.

To solve it:

1. Use a procedure or anonymous program block to try to update the value. If `sql%rowcount` return 0 after the update, perform the insert instead.
2. Use the selection (query for `UPPER(TRIM(name))`) to find the record that was updated.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this. You will need to declare a package to capture your id, otherwise it will not be visible to the SQL statement and you will get a error:

**pls-00231: function** *name* **may not be used in SQL**

So, first create the package with functions to capture and then later access the ID from the merge statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CaptureId
AS
   FUNCTION SaveId(newId IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
   FUNCTION GetId RETURN NUMBER;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CaptureId
AS
   capturedId NUMBER(10);

   FUNCTION SaveId(newId IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
   BEGIN
      capturedId := newId;
      RETURN capturedId;
   END;

   FUNCTION GetId RETURN NUMBER IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN capturedId;
   END;
END;
```

Given a simple table and sequence generator defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(120) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(120) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) ENABLE
);

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_EMPLOYEE;
```

You can then use the package in an anonymous block with your merge statement to capture the id and return it. Note that this is a very simple example and it will not work with array-bound variables unless you rework the package to capture the IDs into a table type. If I get a chance, I may try to put together an example that shows this.

```
BEGIN
   MERGE INTO EMPLOYEE USING (SELECT CaptureId.SaveId(:myInputId) AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
                                     :myFirstName as FIRST_NAME,
                                     :myLastName as LAST_NAME
                                FROM DUAL) B
      ON (A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT (EMPLOYEE_ID,
               FIRST_NAME,
               LAST_NAME)
       VALUES (CaptureId.SaveId(SEQ_EMPLOYEE.NEXTVAL),
               B.FIRST_NAME,
               B.LAST_NAME)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET A.FIRST_NAME= B.FIRST_NAME,
                A.LAST_NAME= B.LAST_NAME;

   SELECT CaptureId.GetId INTO :myOutputId FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Comment: There's another problem with this approach. If you use a qualifier other than the EMPLOYEE_ID in the ON statement (e.g. `A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID OR A.LAST_NAME = B.LAST_NAME`) then you will fail to capture the ID. With that qualifier, you can pass a `NULL` for the `EMPLOYEE_ID` and match on a `LAST_NAME`. If it is not found by `EMPLOYEE_ID`, it will fail to capture the `EMPLOYEE_ID` matched by `LAST_NAME`.